# Transitive ordering of messages in Akka Actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is there any simple way to enforce transitive ordering of messages in Akka?

For example I have

- `A` sending `M1` to `C`
- `A` sending `M2` to `B`
- `B` forwards `M2` to `C`

How do I ensure `C` gets (or interprets) `M1` before `M2` in a simple way?

Comment: As a side note, the documentation states explicitely that this transivity is not guaranteed by the framework - which might not be obvious to anyone. See : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#discussion-message-ordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few of ways you could do this:

1. Have `C` send a reply to `A` when it receives `M1` and delay sending `M2` to `B` before the reply is received.
2. Send `M2` to `C` and have `C` forward it to `B`
3. Put a flag in `M2` to say that it depends on `M1` and have `C` stash `M2` if it arrives before `M1`